# modify the URDF and kinect position turtlebot

Tags: ros, roomba, urdf, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a easy way to modify the URDF file for a turtlebot roomba (metric)?
I need to change the kinect position and also the inertia as i dont use the baseplates. Not really sure how this is done however, is it possible to manually edit the urdf file? If so where is it positioned?

many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46516/modify-the-urdf-and-kinect-position-turtlebot/) by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The urdf of the turtlebot is placed under turtlebot/turtlebot/desription/urdf/.
There are different xacro files.

When I remeber correctly the main file is turtlebot.urdf.xacro which includes the other ones (you will see it in the xml code)

You can get help for editing under http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf. You don't have to build the urdf explicitly it is normally done in the launch file via xacro.

---

Originally posted by [Fabian Saccilotto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2806/fabian-saccilotto/) with karma: 51 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0